# What kinds of data queries are too hard to do on CouchDB (as opposed to SQL)? Seeking concrete examples

Tags: mysql, database, nosql, couchdb

I think CouchDB is really cool and want to use it more. But I'd also like to know ahead of time whether there are any types of data query that are done easily on MySQL but are impossible or very awkward to accomplish in CouchDB.

Please answer with concrete answers or examples instead of just saying that "CouchDB is for documents and MySQL is for relational data." I don't really know what that statement means, since it seems that you can do things functionally equivalent to relational MySQL joins with CouchDB views.

For example, I've read that paginating through a data set is a bit awkward in CouchDB. This is the sort of answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A problem I'm having at the moment is displaying an AJAX grid with contents from a CouchDB database. The equivalent SQL request would be:

```
SELECT * FROM the_table 
WHERE {filter_col} = {filter_value} [ AND ... ]
ORDER BY {order_col}
LIMIT {n} OFFSET {m}
```

It's a pretty simple request to run on a traditional SQL database, but having to perform filtering, ordering and paging all together at the same time is beyond what CouchDB indexing can manage - at least, without creating an insane number of different views.

Answer (score 2):

Couchdb is having hard time with full-text searches (unless external software is used), although mysql isn't particularly good at that, couch is still even worse.

Couchdb isn't going to do a good job when your data model implies multiple and complex relations between objects, after all, it's a document-based system, not relational dbms.

Other than that, IMO couch rules.

EDIT: Particularly when you need to relax, of course! :)

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the motivation behind changing data stores. What problem or architectural challenge are you trying to overcome with MySQL that CouchDB can solve? If at the end of the day there is no difference in functionality or performance then the refactoring to change database platforms cannot be justified.

Have a look at some ORM frameworks, which if implemented correctly can let you swap out the back end databases easily.

Comment: I guess my question, in a sense, is what are the critical differences in functionality between MySQL and CouchDB? Are there some things I take for granted with MySQL that I will discover (unpleasantly) that CouchDB is bad at doing?

Comment: Well for starters, it's terrible at storing relational data… ;)

Comment: Once again it depends on how this large application is using MySQL. If it is nothing more than a flat data store then probably not an issue. However, the first line on the CouchDB web site is "Notice: The 1.0.0 release has a critical bug which can lead to data loss in the default configuration.", which suggest the project is quite immature compared to MySQL. What is the old phrase; never implement version 1.0 of anything.